# 508 Compliant/accessible editing. Letting the user know they're editing an item?

Tags: usability

I'm looking for a way of letting users know that they're editing or in progress of editing a form/item within a panel. On the page there are a series of panels.

The problem is that the user can "leave" a panel and edit another. I'd like to know if there is some sort of defined pattern for letting the user know that they're "in progress" for editing an item or "edited, but not saved".

If I can't find a pattern for this sort of interaction, I might use something like:

**Panel Item Name - Editing**

In the panel title. Thoughts on this?

I will probably also do something for some other visual notification to let users know that the item is still "in progress". Possibly a colored border around the panel or an icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a user leaves a panel to edit another, is it completely dismissed from view?

**Yes?** Then a notification banner that extends the full width of the screen with an action link to continue work on the in-progress item may be beneficial; or, warn that changes could be lost upon attempting to switch panels.

**No?** Add an "in-progress" style to panels that have been modified but not saved. Ideally, this is a darkened background color (10% or so), adding a striped pattern/texture for the background, etc. Be wary of color only solutions as they don't work well for the visually impaired. Different contrast, texture, or symbols tend to work well (coupled with color).

Comment: All panels are collapsed from view (accordion style) until the user decides they are going to edit the item. 

Notification/toastr items will be used to notify users that an item was canceled from editing or saved, but I don't think this kind of pattern would work for "in progress". I guess the best bet would be letting screen-reader users know that they have saved/canceled or moved onto another item. I think you're right about warning the user before they click on another panel.